# Uncaught ReferenceError error is returned: $ is not defined Rails 5

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project with rails 5 and MongoDB.

I need to add a field to take a photo of the person and save along with his personal data. For this I used [a tutorial](https://github.com/brunoocasali/webcamjs-plus-rails).

But when I open my form to be able to take the picture there is only the "Take snapshot" button. And in the console browser the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError error is returned: $ is not defined
> at cam.self-9030b9498041e84bf505d23170c233f678764bfd958a2a6a21985300230b808f.js?
> body = 1: 13 (anonymous) @
> cam.self-9030b9498041e84bf505d23170c233f678764bfd958a2a6a21985300230b808f.js?
> body = 1: 13

In `assets/cam.js`:

```
function take_snapshot(){
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        id = $('[id*="_image"]');

        if (id.length) {
            id.val(data_uri);
        }

        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() { // <-- This is the line of the error
    if ($("#my_camera").length) {
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });

        Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
    }
});
```

Here my application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require webcam.js/webcam.min
//= require cam.js
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require Chart.min
//= require scripts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are missing jQuery.

Have a look on how to include it.

[A possible way of doing that in rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails).

Comment: But I have Jquery exactly like the link you put in the comment above.

Comment: type `$` on the console of the browser, paste the output

Comment: $
ƒ ( selector, context ) {

  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  // Need init if jQuery is called (just allow error to be thrown if not included)
  return new jQuery…

Comment: Alright, seems indeed you have jQuery. Other than that, check the order in which the scripts are imported, maybe jQuery is at the bottom ...

Comment: Look the answer, I placed the order of the Application.js

Comment: ok I solved by changing the order. passing jquery and jquery_ujs before the webacm.min and cam.js libraries. Thanks.

Comment: Then maybe you can accept my answer as correct ? Thanks !